# Echoed, embedded php within javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, apache

**Summary**

Currently I have a webpage in which I am running some javascript to basically allow a user to create an UL list. I want to then process that list, saving it to a file on the server which will need to be done with PHP of course.

**Goal**

The overall goal that I am hoping to solve is how to embed php within javascript. Keep in mind that the javascript itself is being echoed from the html page so everything will be surrounded by single quotes of course.

**What I have tried**

```
function test(){
var ul = document.getElementById("playlist");
var playlist = "";
for (i = 1; i < ul.children.length; i++){
var item = ul.childNodes[i];
playlist += item.innerHTML + String.fromCharCode(13);
}
playlist = playlist.slice(0, -1);


jsvar = \'<?php echo $playlist;?>\';
alert(jsvar);

}
```

The variable playlist is generated perfectly fine. At the end I am trying to do something very simple with the playlist variable. I am simply, for now, trying to just pass the playlist variable int a php script which will then echo it back as a variable for me to display as an alert.

The above code will result in a popup box that has the literal  displayed. For some reason it isn't recognizing that it is a php script but rather treating it as a string.. Am I missing something simple or totally obvious?

I have looked at many posts on SO but all that seem like they would work by using a similar idea as above don't..

Thanks in advance.

**More things I have tried**

I found this online to verify that php5 is installed:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
sudo a2enmod php5
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Apache restarted but I still see the literal string...

**Trial with AJAX**

I tried another method of passing the variable through AJAX and then loading an outside php file. I used the following which loaded the php file but..

```
$.ajax(
{
url: "save_playlist.php",
type: "POST",

data: { id1: playlist},
success: function (result) {
        alert(id);

var url = "save_playlist.php";
window.location.href = url;
}})
```

when having this on my save_playlist.php:

```
session_start();

$a =isset($_POST['id1'])?$_POST['id1']:'not yet';
echo $a ;
```

nothing is passed.. and by the way I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

for my ajax to work.

Comment: What is the extension of the file that `ShuffleList` is in?

Comment: php. The rest of it is a php file being why I am echoing the javascript in the first place.

Comment: If you are getting "<?php echo $playlist;?>" in the alert, then your PHP is not being parsed correctly or at all by your server.

Comment: hm... so perhaps an apache setting? Any idea where to start for that?

Comment: You should look on SO or Google for how to fix issues with Apache not parsing PHP

Comment: You don't want to have your javascript generate php code directly, security wise this is a terrible idea. Instead, you want it to generate Json, or some other serializable data structure, which you'll then unserialize and turn into real php code *server side*.

Comment: Well I understand about security and using JSON but even if I am using it to serialize my data, wouldn't I still need the above embedded php to work (just with the json translation with it too)? I was trying the above example to simplify the problem. I am expecting the php to be processed right away or at least very soon for the simple example above

Comment: Oh, I see, then if it's just to simplify the problem, disregard my comment.

Comment: Thanks for the advice anyway. It is driving me nuts as to why this example won't work for me..

Comment: "I am simply, for now, trying to just pass the playlist variable int a php script which will then echo it back as a variable for me to display as an alert." How do you pass that playlist? Do you perform a form POST/GET?

Comment: There is more code than posted here. The "playlist" is the name of the UL list that is generated in another part of the code. The javascript part, shown above, is simply getting the items and joining them in a delimited string. The function "test()" is then linked to a button.

Comment: I understand that, I only mean to check that you are indeed passing that generated php snippet back *to the server* for it to run it. If you merely keep it client side, it won't be understood as PHP, only as a string.

Comment: So perhaps the javascript side isn't pushing it back to the server correctly to run?

Comment: In order to test your php snippet, you need to send it back to the server (through a form GET or POST), and then have the server `eval` it in the form target script.

Comment: pushing only happens if you tell your javascript code to do it programatically (using ajax), or manually with a form in your HTML, which the user will have to trigger.

Comment: Well, one option that did get me further before was to run my javascript above but tack on the lines var url = "save_playlist.php";
window.location.href = url; to basically load an external php file. Within that php file I could do my php things but I had trouble passing a variable through a POST from javascript that the save_playlist.php could get.  I did try AJAX to do the passing but it hasn't worked properly.

Comment: Ok, I guess you need to work that POST form part out before trying something else. If you have experience making forms in PHP/HTML, you should be able to make a form you'll have to trigger manually. Try that out, see if you can get your PHP snippet to be evaluated server side, and then try the automated way.

Comment: I updated my initial post to show you my ajax method I have tried using. ^